# How do I change a letter in a list then checks if the word is valid on a text file?

Tags: python, tkinter, text-files

I'm working on a project and in this project, if it identifies a specific letter it should be changed using a Tkinter option and reads if it exists in a text file. This is what I have done so far.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

combine = [('THO#N', [(7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9)])]

for word, cord in combine:
    for letter in word:
        if letter == '#':
           def read_save():
               blank_tile = entry_1.get()
               blank_letter = blank_tile
               text_file = open("blanktile.txt", "w")
               text_file.write(blank_letter)
               text_file.close()
               f = open('blanktile.txt','r')
               input_tile = f.read()
               word = [letter.replace('#', input_tile)]
               root.destroy()

           root = tk.Tk()                     
           label_1 = tk.Label(root,text = "Please input a letter for the blank tile")
           label_1.pack()
           entry_1 = tk.Entry(root)
           entry_1.pack(fill=X)
           save_button = tk.Button(root, text="Save", command=read_save)
           save_button.pack(fill=X)

           root.mainloop()
        if word in open('sowpods.txt').read():
            print(word + ' ' + "Exist in the dictionary")
        else:
            print(word + ' ' + "Does not exist in the dictionary")
```

I tried this code but it does not seem to change and it goes directly to not exist in the dictionary. How do I replace a # into a specific letter and checks to see if the word is on a text file? This my text file looks like [image: Click here]. The output should be if I put R on the Tkinter window and click save it will look like THORN and check if this word exists if not it should be removed. Thank you. [Click here to get text file](https://github.com/jesstess/Scrabble/blob/master/scrabble/sowpods.txt)

The output that I want is that if it identifies a # in a word example in THO#N. It will show a pop-up and A user has to input a letter example "R" then press saves then the "R" will replace the '#'. Which makes combine = [('THORN', [(7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9)])]. Also checks the word THORN in a text if it exists if not a pop will show that it does not exist and removes the word with its value in the list.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Can you post your test file as a text not as screenshot? And also show expected result

Comment: Oh okay wait but my test file is quiet huge so im just going to put it in a hyperlink file

Comment: What is `X` here: `fill=X`? Can you provide full code in order to be able to debug it on my PC?

Comment: Oh the x is like an adjust in tkinter. If I use fill=X the widget on the button will occupy all the space in horiztonal if y then vertical.

Comment: Can you just provide full code sample, I don't want to invent something

Comment: The code is actually there. Try it with the imports.

Comment: @Alderven Can you help me pls?

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding: script gets letter, then replaces `#` in word `THO#N` and then searches for word in dictionary:

```
import tkinter as tk

WORD = 'THO#N'

def find_word():
    word = WORD.replace('#', entry.get().upper())
    if word in words:
        label.setvar('Word "{}" exist in the dictionary'.format(word))
        label.config(text='Word "{}" exist in the dictionary'.format(word))
    else:
        label.config(text='Word "{}" not exist in the dictionary'.format(word))

words = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('sowpods.txt')]
root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text='Please input a letter for the blank tile')
label.pack()
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack(fill=tk.X)
save_button = tk.Button(root, text='Save', command=find_word)
save_button.pack(fill=tk.X)
root.mainloop()
```

For example:

- you're entering word `R` and receives result: `Word THORN exist in the dictionary`
- you're entering word `A` and receives result: `Word THOAN not exist in the dictionary`

[image] [image]

Comment: If I click save will combine = [('THO#N', [(7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9)])] becomes combine = [('THORN', [(7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9)])]?

Comment: What does these letters mean?

Comment: the letters are just coordinates I just want to know if it identifies # in a word a pop up message will display and if a letter will be specified and clicks save it will change # into a specific letter

Comment: Coordinates of what?

Comment: The project that I am making is for detecting scrabble so i need those coordinates to find where they are placed. My problem is that if a player puts a blank tile which is the # it should recognize it and using the pop up menu will replace into a specific letter.

Comment: Can you give step by step example of this?